# Laravel 4: Binding/linking two users together

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a unittest system. At some point I want to bind two users together in order to make an assignment for those two.

So when the admin chooses to link two students together the system should figure out how to, maybe using the ID numbers of the both users.  I have an idea on how implement this, but not very clear.

Comment: What is the idea that you have?

Comment: it's basically a Unittest system which the admin ( the teacher)  is going to link two students together to make an assignment. The thing I can't figure out is how to link those two students together. The admin is going to use UI interface selecting two students... Let me know if you understand the meaning.